# Facebook app authentication duplicates data at my DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook

After reading a lot, finally my fb app is doing what i expected (collect data and store it at my DB). However, if the user goes back to the app in the page tab (the user is already logged in the app) the entry in the table will be repeated. 
As I read in the tutorials there is a part in my code that verifies if the user is already in the DB, if this is a new user then it will record the data, if not nothing.

Please take a look at my code and guide me to solve it. Thanks

I get no error, but it seems that the problem might be around here :

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND  oauth_uid = ". $user_profile['id']);  
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 define('db_user','xxx');
 define('db_password','xxx');
 define('db_host','xxx.xxx.com');
 define('db_name','xxx');

 // Connect to MySQL
 $dbc = @mysql_connect (db_host, db_user, db_password) OR die ('Could not connect to   MySQL: ' . mysql_error() );
// Select the correct database
mysql_select_db (db_name) OR die ('Could not select the database: ' . mysql_error() );
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbc);

require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxx',
'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true));


 // Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();

 // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
 //
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$fbuid = $facebook->getUser();
 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');



   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e);
   $user = null;
   }
     }else{
   header('Location: index.php');

    }
    //know if the user is in the db 
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND oauth_uid = ". $user_profile['id']);  
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  


    if(empty($result)){ 
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, first_name, last_name, birthday, email, pic_square ) VALUES    ('facebook', {$user_profile['id']}, '{$user_profile['name']}', '{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['birthday']}','{$user_profile['email']}', '{$user_profile['pic_square']}')");  
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());  
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die ( mysql_error () );  


}  


   // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
     $paramsout = array('next'=>'http://www.mywebsite.com/test/logout.php');
     $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($paramsout);
     }
     ?>
     <html><body>welcome</body></html>
```

Comment: You could configure the database so that the email address is a unique and indexed field. This would help with preventing duplicated data.

Comment: @kobaltz.. thanks :D I will read on how to do that.